# Is state saved in TaskManager's memory regardless of state back end?

Tags: apache-flink

I know I can set the state backend both in the flink's configuration file(flink-conf.yaml) globally
or set in the per-job scope.

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()
env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("hdfs://namenode:40010/flink/checkpoints"))
```

I have one question here:

Where are the state data that belongs to the TasManager saved in `TaskManager` while the flink job keeps running? I mean that when one checkpoint is done,the checkpointed data will be saved in HDFS(chk-XXX) or RocksDB, but while the flink job keeps running, the taskManager will accumulate more and more states belonging to this task manager, are they always saved in memory?

If they are kept in memory, then the checkpoint data can't be too large,or else OOM may occur.

Can I use RocksDB in TaskManager process to save the TM's states data? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the FsStateBackend, the working state for each task manager is in memory (on the JVM heap), and state backups (checkpoints) go to a distributed file system, e.g., HDFS.

With the RocksDBStateBackend, the working state for each task manager is in a local RocksDB instance, i.e., on the local disk, and again, the state backups (checkpoints) go to a distributed file system, e.g., HDFS.

Flink never stores checkpoint data in RocksDB. That's not the role it plays. RocksDB is used as an ephemeral, embedded data store whose contents can be lost in the event that a task manager fails. This is an alternative to keeping the working state in memory (where it can also be lost when a task manager fails).